# Flutter: Expanded IconButton still shows under the Container

Tags: flutter

```
       AnimatedContainer(
               ...
                child: Container(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            width:60,
                            height:50,
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              print('what');
                            },
                            child: Container(
                              height: 50,
                              child: Column(
                                children: [
                                  Expanded(
                                    child: Text('asdf'),
                                  ),
                                  Expanded(
                                    child: IconButton(
                                      icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                                      onPressed: () {},
                                    ),
```

I have this `AnimatedContainer` widget here. My `Text()` widget and `RaisedButton` widget are hidden inside the box. They appear as the `AnimatedContainer` expand. However, my `IconButton` doesn't.

[image]

Also, `Icon` widget also stays like `IconButton` widget. How can I make it appear when the `AnimatedContainer` is stretched like the `Text` widget?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified your code, hope this is what u want.

```
class _RowStructureState extends State<RowStructure> {
  bool pressed = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          pressed = !pressed;
        });
        print(pressed);
      },
      child: Column(children: <Widget>[
        AnimatedContainer(
          height: pressed ? 120 : 50,
          color: Colors.green,
          duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 50,
                width: 50,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              Positioned(
                bottom:0,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text('asd'),
                    IconButton(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                      icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit,),
                      onPressed: pressed?(){}:null,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )

            ],
          ),
        )
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Dang! Didn't think of using Stack this way!